# How to make sure that a Point A moving in the direction V reaches at Point B?

Tags: xna, c++, mathematics, algorithm, vector

Let say I have,
[image]

Point A(X1,Y1) moving in the direction V(W, H). I need to make sure that it reaches B(X2,Y2). I think I need to subtract some value in Point A(X1, X2). But not know what? I also sure that the direction is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can get the displacement from `A` to `B` by subtraction.  I'm not sure if your direction `V` is normalized or not, but if you normalize the direction and normalize the displacement vector, `A` will reach `B` if those vectors are equal.</strike>

```
Vector2 displacement = B - A;
displacement.Normalize();
V.Normalize();

if(displacement == V)
{
    // A will reach B if you get in here
}
```

Note:  I'm rusty on my XNA so the specific functions you may need to call may be a little off, but the concept should work.

**Post-clarification Edit:**

```
V.Normalize();
float distance = 10.0f;  //Change this value to whatever distance you want
Point A = B - V * distance;
```

Comment: I need to make sure that it must reached there. What I can do with Point A.

Comment: What is it, specifically, that you need to calculate?  Do you mean that you have `A` and `B` and need to calculate `V`?

Comment: Your XNA is perfectly fine, but since vectors store floating point values you'd have to do an almost-exactly-equal check (because of ye olde classic difference of one millionth).

Comment: No, I need to make sure that Point B is reached. I need to do something with Point A. I cannot change Vector V. I cannot change Point B.

Comment: So...  you want to move point `A` in direction `V` (toward `B`)?  Have you tried `A += V`?

Comment: This will not work. I need to make sure that A moving through in direction V should always reach at B. I need to move A in such a way that after starting from new A, it will reach B.

Comment: Oh, so you need a new Point `A` where `V` represents the displacement from `B` to `A`?

Comment: Yes I need new A. But V is fixed. V is not the displacement from B to A. Also, B is fixed.

Comment: Then, try my new solution above.  If I understand correctly, that's all you need.

Comment: Wait, I will check it my application.

Comment: It, works. Thanks. Is it possible to get a point near to A.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but it sounds like a different question you could formulate and ask as a new question on the site.

Comment: @chaosTechnician, It is not diffrent. It's same.  B - V is perfactly works for me. But it is very far away from A. I need a Point near to A. So, that moving in direction V I can reach B. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3117/discussion-between-chaostechnician-and-user960567)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a point close to `A` such that moving from that point in the direction `v` will eventually reach `B`.

The point closest to `A` is the projection of `A` on the line `(B,v)`. It is computed as follows:

```
newA = B - dot(B - A, V) / dot(V, V) * V;
```

[image: projection]

Comment: Is dot means dot product? If no then can you please explain dot method in language agnostic way.

Comment: @user960567 yes, `dot()` is meant as the dot product.

Comment: Can you please explain how you found this formula?

Comment: @user960567 it's pretty straightforward from the [projection of vector AB on the line (B,v)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Projection.html)

Comment: Also, why you are subtracting from Point B.

Comment: OK, got it Thanks. But I think you are talking about Projection of V vector onto B-V vector.